# Reset Password e- mail... recent email should work , not previous

Tags: c#, asp.net

Reset Password Email - If  two reset Password email has been sent , then the recent one should only work. Previous one should n't redirect to a reset password page.. Provide me a hint what can i do to make it work as required

Comment: keep a flag in you application or database which is the recent one and which are others

Answer (score 2):

Add a `VerificationCode-column` to the database where the passwords are saved

```
Username  Password   VerificationCode
user1     Pass1      dfsdb-dfb-anda
```

Password reset link will consist of a randomly generated verificationCode (as a query parameter).

```
/account/ResetPassword?user=user1&VerificationCode=dfsdb-dfb-anda
```

On receiving a request from reset form, to change password, verify the username and verificationCode combination. Once the user has changed the password, delete the verification code from the database.